# Python unit test passes locally, but fails in Jenkins when comparing dates

Tags: python, unit-testing, jenkins

The following test passes locally, because Locally it's EST:

```
    def test_get_local_ts(self):
        dt = Utils.get_local_ts().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        dt1 = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        self.assertEqual(dt, dt1)
```

But fails when running in a Jenkins pipeline.

Because Jenkins server is running on UTC time, but the method `get_local_ts` is returning the local time.

And so this error happens:

> self.assertEqual(dt, dt1)

> AssertionError: '2021-12-16' != '2021-12-17'

Also, this will only fail when running it after 7 PM EST, when UTC rolls over to next day.

How can I get this to pass locally and in Jenkins at any time?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "Jenkins server is running on UTC time" and "get_local_ts is returning the local time"? Have you tried to use tz parameter for datetime.now() so that you are dealing with timezone aware objects?

Answer (score 0):

If your unit tests involve datetime objects, then you should probably set the time zone as part of your test setup. A unit test should run under controlled conditions without depending on external factors.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.tzset